# What binding will be better for Image whether binding Byte[] or string for good performance

Tags: wpf, image, binding

I am working on WPF project, where the window contains list of users and their profile images. The following is the User model.

```
public class UserModel
    {
        public Guid? Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
    }
```

And, this is how I am binding the UserImage

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="0" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Margin="0,1,0,0" Width="35" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <ImageBrush  ImageSource="{Binding ProfileImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
```

But, here I just need a clarification to make no performance issues while loading these image. I've been suggested to use byte[] fro images instead of string in order to avoid performance issues.

Can somebody please clarify me on this, what will be the better binding to display images to reduces performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the image data into a byte array, then you can directly bind the Source property of an Image control to this property without the need for any converter.

```
public class UserModel
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProfileImage { get; set; }
}


<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserModelCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserModel}">
            <Grid
                Height="32"
                Margin="4"
                Focusable="False">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Source="{Binding ProfileImage}"
                    Stretch="Uniform" />

                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

To avoid blocking the UI thread, especially if you have a large list of users and you only want to fetch the images on demand when that item is being displayed, I suggest the use of an asynchronous property.

```
/// <summary>
/// A read only property where the value is fetched once when required, in an async manner, and then cached for future use.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// in Xaml, bind to perAsyncPropertyInstance.Value
/// </remarks>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class perAsyncProperty<T> : perViewModelBase where T : class
{
    private readonly Func<Task<T>> _fetchValue;

    public perAsyncProperty(Func<Task<T>> fetchValue)
    {
        _fetchValue = fetchValue;
    }

    private bool _fetchingValue;

    private T _value;

    /// <summary>
    /// The property's value - use this as the source of data binding.
    /// </summary>
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_value != null || _fetchingValue)
            {
                return _value;
            }

            _fetchingValue = true;

            // can't use await inside a property getter, so use a continuation instead
            _fetchValue()
                .EvaluateFunctionWithTimeoutAsync(FetchValueTimeOut)
                .ContinueWith(FetchValueContinuation);

            // Local function to refresh Value once the data fetch task has completed
            async void FetchValueContinuation(Task<perAsyncFunctionResponse<T>> task)
            {
                var taskResult = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (taskResult.IsCompletedOk)
                {
                    Value = taskResult.Data;
                }
                else if (taskResult.IsTimedOut)
                {
                    OnTimeOutAction?.Invoke(taskResult);
                }
                else if (taskResult.IsError)
                {
                    OnErrorAction?.Invoke(taskResult);
                }

                _fetchingValue = false;
            }

            return _value;
        }
        private set => Set(nameof(Value), ref _value, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Timeout value for FetchValue invocation
    /// </summary>
    public TimeSpan FetchValueTimeOut { get; set; } = perTimeSpanHelper.Forever;

    /// <summary>
    /// Optional action to perform if FetchValue generates an error.
    /// </summary>
    public Action<perAsyncFunctionResponse<T>> OnErrorAction { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Optional action to perform if FetchValue times out.
    /// </summary>
    public Action<perAsyncFunctionResponse<T>> OnTimeOutAction { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clear Value and force it to be re-fetched then next time it is read.
    /// </summary>
    public void ResetValue()
    {
        _fetchingValue = false;
        Value = null;
    }
}


public class perBytesFromFileAsyncProperty : perAsyncProperty<byte[]>
{
    public perBytesFromFileAsyncProperty(string filePath) : base(() => FetchData(filePath))
    {
    }

    private static Task<byte[]> FetchData(string filePath)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("loading file - " + filePath);
        return perIOAsync.ReadAllBytesFromFileRawAsync(filePath);
    }
}


public class perBytesFromUrlAsyncProperty : perAsyncProperty<byte[]>
{
    public perBytesFromUrlAsyncProperty(string url): base(() => FetchData(url))
    {
    }

    private static Task<byte[]> FetchData(string url)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("downloading Url - " + url);
        return perIOAsync.ReadAllBytesFromUrlRawAsync(url);
    }
}
```

Use the appropriate version depending on whether your string for the image source is a file path or web url.

Now the UserModel and view binding can be coded as

```
public class UserModel
{
    public UserModel (Guid id, string name, string imageFilePath)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        ProfileImage = new perBytesFromFileAsyncProperty(imageFilePath);
    }

    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public perBytesFromFileAsyncProperty ProfileImage { get; set; }
}


<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserModelCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserModel}">
            <Grid
                Height="32"
                Margin="4"
                Focusable="False">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Source="{Binding ProfileImage.Value}"
                    Stretch="Uniform" />

                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

More details on my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/c-async-await-part-2/).

Answer (score 1):

The string cannot be a drawing.
The string contains the path (Uri) of the picture.
The binding will automatically check for the presence of an image by the specified Uri, and if it is there, it will convert it to ImageSource and transfer it to the property.

But the byte [] array directly contains the image data.
The binding cannot automatically convert this array to ImageSource type.
Therefore, you need to get the byte [] array yourself, convert it to one of the ImageSource types, and only then provide it in the ProfileImage property, from where the binding can pick it up.

The first variant (with a string) is simpler, but with large sizes of images, slow access to them, a large number of them, problems with GUI lags may arise.
Since getting the picture by binding will take place in the main GUI thread (Dispatcher).

In the second case, most of the work can be done asynchronously.